# How should I remedy a ground wire in a switch box which was burnt by a short?

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I was replacing a light switch with a dimmer on a 3way pole.  Installed last night and it worked fine except a very low hum.  I attempted to “fix” the hum by pulling it out today. I turned off the power to that fuse but didn’t realize the other 3way switch had an open current to a different fuse.  When I pulled out the dimmer there was a small spark as the ground wire brushed against the neutral screw on the other unit burning the ground wire.

Is this salvageable (is it possible to cut the wire off at the burn mark or would that be too short?) and if not about how much would that cost (by an electrician) to replace?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You've got a 3-way circuit with each switch being powered from a different breaker? You've got _far_ more serious issues than a bit of burn mark on a ground wire! You'll probably want an electrician to go over the whole house to figure out what other sever code violations have been committed.

Comment: @FreeMan ugh.  I really consider myself lucky then because last night when I installed this the other fuse was kept on (I used light from a lamp to work) and apparently I could’ve killed myself lol.  That’s why i didn’t think I had to turn it off this morning ‍

Comment: You seem to have two switches in that box.  Can you confirm that it is the other switch on a different circuit, or the other three way switch for the same light on another fuse/breaker?  One not the best the other very bad.  I would think the first and just snip and splice the ground, after making sure the other breaker is off also.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn’t make that clear.  There are two switches in this gang - one with the dimmer that I’m working on, and the other with a regular switch.  They are both on my kitchen lights fuse - the dimmer is paired with a 4gang switch that is also in the kitchen.  The one on the right (normal switch) is paired w a 3way switch in my living room.  I think the problem was the living room switch was flipped on & that’s why the circuit was still open.

Comment: Also I thought there was a code that the wires had to be at least six inches from the receptacle box?  That’s why I was hesitant to cut off the burn and do a pigtail..  As an aside, is a light hum noise to be expected from a dimmer switch?  The electrician I spoke to said yes but I would assume humming from the actual dimmer is not a good look.

Comment: Two switches in the same box controlling two different lights can be on different fuses/breakers.  Different switches controlling the same light/s cannot be on different fuses/breakers.  Only one fuse for the light and it's switches.  Six inches yes, but short wires can be lengthen with pigtails.  Hums and low power(lights) usually do not go together, even high power users in a house a hum is odd.  The transformer on the pole might have a hum.

Comment: Read this incorrectly.  Ok, that makes sense.  And ok, perhaps that is the issue?  I think all of our wiring is underground with conduit boxes… there are no poles in our neighborhood.